# Cognos Report Studio (case statement) - Syntax error

Tags: db2, cognos, db2-luw, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have a case statement in Cognos report studio in which if the date is 1st of the current month of previous year then it should fetch data for last whole month (1 to the last date) data of the previous year. I think it is a syntax error. Below is the code that I'm sharing.Thanks in advance! Please let me know in case of concerns.

```
case when 
[Corporate Calendar_BL].[Receive Date Details].[Receive Date - RD] = _first_of_month(_add_years(current_date,-1))
then 
[Corporate Calendar_BL].[Receive Date Details].[Receive Date - RD] 
  between
_first_of_month(_add_months(_add_years(current_date,-1),-1))
   and
_last_of_month (_add_months(_add_years(current_date,-1),-1))
end
```

Comment: You tagged both mysql and Db2. Which RDBMS should run that SQL ?   Also *which RBBMS version* and *which operating system runs the database*.

Comment: It is running on windows 7

Comment: Will the SQL run against mysql or Db2,  and which version?

Comment: SQL runs in DB2

Comment: Version is Sqldbx 10.5

Comment: As-of today, your code evaluates to this: `case when [mydate] = 2018-01-01 then [mydate] between 2017-12-01 and 2017-12-31 end`  It will always return NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is correct. However, it looks like you are using a CASE statement in a filter. Cognos is picky about CASE syntax in filters. It requires you to put both the condition and the result in parentheses. Try this:

```
case when 
([Corporate Calendar_BL].[Receive Date Details].[Receive Date - RD] = _first_of_month(_add_years(current_date,-1)))
then 
([Corporate Calendar_BL].[Receive Date Details].[Receive Date - RD]
  between
_first_of_month(_add_months(_add_years(current_date,-1),-1))
   and
_last_of_month (_add_months(_add_years(current_date,-1),-1)))
end
```

Here's an alternate syntax that should also work:

```
extract(year,current_date) - 1 = extract(year, [Corporate Calendar_BL].[Receive Date Details].[Receive Date - RD])
AND 
extract(month,current_date) = extract(month, [Corporate Calendar_BL].[Receive Date Details].[Receive Date - RD])
```

**==CORRECTION==**

**It's come to my attention that my answer is not quite correct even though it was accepted. Please see below for clarification.**

The CASE WHEN I provided will generate an error because the condition references fluctuating values that vary by source row. When I constructed the answer I focused on the syntactical problems without evaulating the logic. In order for this type of logic to work, the condition right after CASE WHEN should reference a single value for the entire query. This can be a user-supplied parameter or a function or constant returning a single value for the entire query, such as:

```
(year(current_date) = 2018)
```

or

```
(?param? = 'foo')
```

The following is a very simple example that works in 10.2 and can be used as a template:

```
CASE 
WHEN (?param? = 'foo') 
THEN (extract(year,[Date]) = 2018)
ELSE (extract(year,[Date]) = 2017)
END
```

**Similarly, my alternative logic is correct in form but not in logic because I again lifted the logic straight from the question without examination. The logic as constructed will never return true. A modified corrected version is as follows:**

```
_first_of_month(current_date) = current_date /* Today is the first day of the month */
AND month(_add_months(current_date,-1)) = month([Corporate Calendar_BL].[Receive Date Details].[Receive Date - RD]) /* The month of the row matches the previous month */
AND year(_add_years(current_date,-1)) = year([Corporate Calendar_BL].[Receive Date Details].[Receive Date - RD]) /* The year of the row matches the previous year */
```

This will give you all of the previous month's data for last year if ran on the first day of any month. If you ran it in November 1, 2018, you'd get data for the entire month of October 2017. If you ran it January 1, 2018, you'd get data for the entire month of December 2016 etc.

Comment: Thanks Johnsonium. Much appreciated.Get to learn that cognos doesn't support conditional filters.Thanks again : )

Comment: It does support conditional filters but it's just picky about the syntax.

Comment: @Johnsonium Is this a feature of DB2?  I tried your CASE statement in a Cognos 11.0.7 filter against MS SQL Server 2016 and it failed.  `Filter expressions must evaluate to Boolean.`

Comment: @dougp When I created this answer, I simply transplanted his logic into the proper form. In reality, for it to work the CASE WHEN condition has to be universal for the entire query rather than apply to each row. That's why you are receiving the error. This works: `CASE 
WHEN (?param? = 'foo') 
THEN (extract(year,[Date]) = 2018)
ELSE (extract(year,[Date]) = 2017)
END`. You don't get the error because the condition is universal and not row-based.

Comment: @Johnsonium I see.  This doesn't run in MS SQL.  Cognos generates SQL like `datepart(year,"Table"."Date") = 2017`.  I think it's unfortunate that Cognos allows SQL-like syntax for code that will be used only by the parser.  Knowing that at some point in the future I'll be moving to another reporting tool (change is inevitable), I try to develop reports in a way that the code is easier to convert to something I can run directly on the database server.  I also don't understand why people want to overcomplicate solutions.  I like your alternate syntax much better.

Comment: That makes sense. Howver, in some situations the opposite is true; The BI platform changes less often than the underlying data source vendor. That's the way it is where I work. In that situation I recommend using Cognos-specific functions that will be automatically converted to vendor-specific syntax by Cognos after changing data sources.

Comment: @Johnsonium - whatever you said in above comment trail is absolutely true. Adding to this, initially when you sent out the solution for my asked question , I went with the alternate sysntax which was absolutely works fine for me because I don't wanted make my query more complicated .. I'm not sure about the 1st syntax that you sent out because I never been used it so far. Anyway thank you for updating/correcting your solution

Comment: @Johnsonium Off topic, but I don't see another way to ask.  You have a lot of reputation points.  Would you mind creating a tag for `cognos-11`?

Comment: I can create tags. However, the way to do so is add a new tag to a question. I'd have to ask a Cognos 11 related question. I currently work in 10.2, so I wouldn't have a germane question to ask.

Comment: @Johnsonium Can you add it to other users' questions?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952545/cognos-reporting-javascript-prompt-button-events

Comment: @doubp I just added it. We'll see if it gets approved.

Answer (score 0):

For Db2-LUW v10.5, these predicates may help you build the SQL you need:

```
-- Date of the first-day of the current month last year:

date(year(current date - 1 year)||'-'||month(current date)||'-01')

-- Date of the last-day of the current month last year:

date(year(current date - 1 year)||'-'||month(current date+ 1 month)||'-01') - 1 day
```

Comment: Hello Mao, yours logic is correct but my question is, syntax is not been used properly in my code. i mean error is somewhere in "between operator" And also can you check for the brackets ?

Comment: Use a WHERE clause on a query to select rows.  Use a CASE expression only to adjust column values in the result-set of the query, but not the rows you want to filter.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the possibility of erroring because it returns a NULL, your (Johnsonium's) code is equivalent to this:

```
[Corporate Calendar_BL].[Receive Date Details].[Receive Date - RD] = _first_of_month(_add_years(current_date,-1))
and (
    [Corporate Calendar_BL].[Receive Date Details].[Receive Date - RD] between
        _first_of_month(_add_months(_add_years(current_date,-1),-1)) and
        _last_of_month (_add_months(_add_years(current_date,-1),-1))
    )
```

With no ELSE clause, your original code should return TRUE or NULL.  Unfortunately, it will never return TRUE.  I would not assume that NULL will be handled as FALSE.  If you must use the CASE statement, I would add an ELSE clause.  Perhaps...

```
ELSE (1=2)
```

But since it will never return TRUE, I'm not sure what you're going for here.  If you are trying to ensure your query never returns results, a filter containing...

```
1=2
```

...is much simpler.