# CASE statement in Report Studio filters

Tags: filter, db2, case-statement, cognos-8

I wrote the following `CASE` statement in a Report Studio filter (Cognos 8 running on DB2):

```
CASE
    WHEN (
        _WEEK_OF_YEAR(?paramDate?) > _WEEK_OF_YEAR(_ADD_MONTHS(?paramDate?; -3))
    )
    THEN (
        [BusinessView].[QueryItem].[Week] <= _WEEK_OF_YEAR(?paramDate?)
        AND [BusinessView].[QueryItem].[Week] >= _WEEK_OF_YEAR(_ADD_MONTHS(?paramDate?; -3))
        AND [BusinessView].[QueryItem].[Year] = _YEAR(?paramDate?)
    )
    ELSE (
        ([BusinessView].[QueryItem].[Week] <= _WEEK_OF_YEAR(?paramDate?)
            AND [BusinessView].[QueryItem].[Year] = _YEAR(?paramDate?))
        OR ([BusinessView].[QueryItem].[Week] >= _WEEK_OF_YEAR(_ADD_MONTHS(?paramDate?; -3))
            AND [BusinessView].[QueryItem].[Year] = _YEAR(_ADD_MONTHS(?paramDate?; -3)))
    )
END
```

But I get the error `XQE-PLN-0312: Filter expressions must evaluate to Boolean`. Notice that the expressions under both `WHEN` and `THEN` and `ELSE` all **do** evaluate to boolean. Also, such expressions all work when put individually in a filter. So I argue the problem is about the CASE statement itself.
Also notice that I wrote other `CASE` filters in other reports and they work as I expect. Hence I suspect some trouble with date functions interacting with `CASE`.

I found out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099573/cognos-report-studio-case-statement-syntax-error) answer, but it didn't fix the problem: as you can see in my code I already put all the parentheses in place.

**Please don't suggest me to avoid the `CASE` statement and use instead AND and OR alone; this actually works, but I would like to understand how to make the `CASE` working as well.**

Comment: It would be helpful if you described the desired outcome.  I suspect most people won't respond to "fix my code" with no actual specifications.  I looked at the example you refer to and it's not something I would use.  There's no ELSE clause in the CASE statement.  NULL is neither true nor false, so I wouldn't bother to predict what that would do.  I'd write it differently. Besides, that example will never return TRUE so the query would always return 0 rows.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  I see from the related post that this will apparently work in DB2.  I can't make the accepted answer for that post work in MS SQL Server.

Comment: @dougp I confirm I'm using DB2, now I added this info to the question. By the way, the desired outcome depends on the underlying data. How can I give you some clue about? My true problem here is that I have three logical conditions which work fine individually, but which give me an error when inserted in a `CASE` statement. I mean, the `CASE` gives not an unexpected output... it gives an error. The report doesn't run.

Comment: I don't use DB2, so I can't help you troubleshoot there.  Avoiding the CASE statement will make the expression slightly more readable.  More importantly, it's cross-platform compatible and more likely to work.  You already have a nested structure involving AND and OR.  Why not just complete that?

One other thing I notice:  Cognos is case-sensitive.  Also, function arguments are separated by commas.  Try using `_week_of_year(?paramDate?)`, `_year()` and `_add_months(?paramDate?, -3)`.

Comment: +dougp Cognos functions are not case sensitive. Both _ADD_MONTHS and _add_months are equally valid.

Comment: @dougp, again, the expressions inside the `CASE` are correct: they work fine when used individually inside a filter. Using just `AND` and `OR` works as well. But since the `CASE` is logically equivalent, and far more intuitive to me, I would like it to work as well. It can't be that an IBM software is not able to work with `CASE`, so I would like to know how to do. However I understand that you don't use DB2, so thanks anyway for helping.

Comment: Apparently, this may not even work in DB2.  This is Cognos-specific syntax.  Cognos parses it and generates SQL to send to the db server.  Perhaps the problem is with _week_of_year and/or _add_months.  Maybe Cognos can't compute the values to result in `number1 > number2`, so it's generating SQL to do so (`datepart(week,?paramDate?) > datepart(week,dateadd(month,-3,?paramDate?)` in MS SQL) and failing when it tries to validate the SQL it wants to send to the db server.  With the calculations you have within the CASE statement, you're better off using standard SQL syntax (AND/OR) or a macro

Answer (score 0):

There is no need any [if] or [case] statement. Just write filter conditions with logical operators.

Comment: As I wrote at the end of my question: Please don't suggest me to avoid the CASE statement and use instead AND and OR alone; this actually works, but I would like to understand how to make the CASE working as well.

Answer (score -1):

Your CASE statement is invalid.  All paths of a CASE statement must return a value.  Try running your result expressions independently of the CASE statement.  For example...

```
[BusinessView].[QueryItem].[Week] <= _WEEK_OF_YEAR(?paramDate?)
AND [BusinessView].[QueryItem].[Week] >= _WEEK_OF_YEAR(_ADD_MONTHS(?paramDate?; -3))
AND [BusinessView].[QueryItem].[Year] = _YEAR(?paramDate?)
```

...will result in an error.

Also, "The data types of *else_result_expression* and any *result_expression* must be the same or must be an implicit conversion."  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

The result of a filter must be either true or false.

So something like this?

```
CASE
  WHEN A=B
    THEN 'value1'
  WHEN A=C
    THEN 'value2'
  ELSE 'value3'
END = 'value3'
```

Comment: As you can see from my code I compare years with years and weeks with weeks, and I only do comparisons like `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`, `=`. Also, as I wrote, my "expressions all work when put individually in a filter". So I argue the expression are correct. On the other hand, I can't rewrite my code in the form you suggested. I'm not computing a value to be compared, I'm doing mixed comparisons which involve different fields. Further, I wrote other CASE filters in other reports and they work as I expect.

Comment: And I argue that you didn't bother to run `[BusinessView].[QueryItem].[Week] <= _WEEK_OF_YEAR(?paramDate?)
AND [BusinessView].[QueryItem].[Week] >= _WEEK_OF_YEAR(_ADD_MONTHS(?paramDate?; -3))
AND [BusinessView].[QueryItem].[Year] = _YEAR(?paramDate?)` all by itself.  If you had, you would notice it doesn't work.  Here's a simpler example:  `select 'asdf' < 'qwer'`  This returns `Incorrect syntax near '<'.`

Comment: If you are not computing a value to be compared, why is it a filter?  Wouldn't that be a data item?

Comment: Of course I did, and in fact I wrote "such expressions all work when put individually in a filter" in my question. And it works perfectly: I don't get an error and the report returns exactly the rows I expect. However I don't understand your last suggestion. My code is a filter since it glues together a sequence of boolean conditions by means of logic operators (`AND`, `OR`) and constructs (`CASE`).

Comment: dougp, you are not correct. CASE is parsed differently when used in a Data Item versus a filter. In a data item, the result is a value, like your generic example. However, when used in a filter, the result is a filter itself which is then applied to the entire result set. One of the caveats is your CASE condition should be evaluated for the entire report rather than relying on row by row values. His example does this by examining the passed in parameter. It may be a limitation of Cognos 8 versus Cognos 10+. I tested this successfully with 10.

Comment: @Johnsonium the strange thing is that I implemented another `CASE` filter in another report (still in Cognos 8), and it works. The only difference I can spot between the two is that this one encompasses date functions. Do you think the limitation could involve the interaction between `CASE` and date functions? Sounds plausible in your opinion?

Comment: @VanniRovera Have you tried casting ?paramDate? as a date before applying data functions? All Cognos parameters are of type string unless cast to something else. It's a long shot as you'd think you'd get a different error if the problem was data type.

Comment: Have you tried running your code directly against the database through whatever management console DB2 uses (like SSMS for SQL Server)?

Comment: @Johnsonium I put the expression under the `THEN` in an individual filter and then I tried both `CAST(?paramDate?, date)` and `TO_DATE(?paramDate?, 'YYMMDD')` but I get a syntax error (XQE-V5-0011 in both cases). Not sure how to do this. Notice however that all of the three expressions work as individual filters even without casting, so I think this is not a casting problem. Also consider that `?paramDate?` is specified by the user via a Date Prompt, so I guess Cognos automatically casts it to date.

Comment: @VanniRovera Cognos doesn't automatically cast to a date but some (most?) DB vendors do implicit conversion. If the value looks like it should be a different type depending on how it's being used it will attempt to convert it for you.